# why regex split add to pattern \r\n

Tags: c#, regex, split

I want to split the body of article by html div tag so I have a pattern to search div.
the problem is that the pattern also  split \r\n 
 [enter image description here][1]

```
string pattern = @"<div[^<>]*>(.*?)</div>";
string[] bodyParagraphsnew = Regex.Split(body, pattern,RegexOptions.None);
Response.Write("num of paragraph =" + bodyParagraphsnew.Length);
for (int i = 0; i < bodyParagraphsnew.Length; i++)
{
    Response.Write("bodyParagraphs" + i + "= " + bodyParagraphsnew[i]+ Environment.NewLine);
}
```

When I debug this code I see a lot of "\r\n" in the array bodyParagraphsnew.

Its seen that the pattern include split by the string "\r\n" 
I try to replace \r\n to string empty and i hoped that bodyParagraphsnew length will change.but not.I got instead of item(in array) that contain \r\n it contain "" 
WHY?

here is link to image https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hxqki.gif that explain the problem

Comment: Are you able to show us an example of a body string that causes this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are seeing is the text that is between the end of the first </div> tag and the start of the next <div> tag. This is what [`Split`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev12.query?appId=Dev12IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Split);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework) does, it finds the text **between** the Regular Expression matches.

What is curious here though is that you are also going to get the text between the open and close tags because you put brackets in your string forming a [capturing group](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc(v=vs.110).aspx#grouping_constructs). Consider the following program:

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string body = "<div>some text</div>\r\n<div>some more text</div>";

        string pattern = @"<div[^>]*?>(.*?)</div>";
        string[] bodyParagraphsnew = Regex.Split(body, pattern, RegexOptions.None);
        Console.WriteLine("num of paragraph =" + bodyParagraphsnew.Length);
        for (int i = 0; i < bodyParagraphsnew.Length; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("bodyParagraphs {0}: '{1}'", i, bodyParagraphsnew[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

What you will get from this is:

1. "" - An empty string taken from before the first <div>.
2. "some text" - The contents of the first <div>, because of the capturing group.
3. "\r\n" - The text between the end of the first </div> and the start of the last <div>.
4. "some more text" - The contents of the second div, again because of the capturing group.
5. "" - An empty string taken from after the last </div>.

What you are probably after is the contents of the div tags. This can **kind of** be achieved using this code:

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string body = "<div>some text</div>\r\n<div>some more text</div>";

        string pattern = @"<div[^>]*?>(.*?)</div>";
        MatchCollection bodyParagraphsnew = Regex.Matches(body, pattern, RegexOptions.None);
        Console.WriteLine("num of paragraph =" + bodyParagraphsnew.Count);
        for (int i = 0; i < bodyParagraphsnew.Count; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("bodyParagraphs {0}: '{1}'", i, bodyParagraphsnew[i].Groups[1].Value);
        }
    }
}
```

**Note however that in HTML, div tags can be nested within each other**. For example, the following is a valid HTML string:

```
string test = "<div>Outer div<div>inner div</div>outer div again</div>";
```

**With this kind of situation Regular expressions are not going to work!** This is largely due to HTML not being a [Regular Language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_language). To deal with this situation you are going to need to write a Parser (of which regular expressions are only a small part). However personally I wouldn't bother as there are plenty of open source HTML parsers already available [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) for example.

Answer (score 0):

Two possibilies

1. you use llist instead of array and list.remove
2. you go through your array search for \r\n and remove it by index

   ```
   if(bodyParagraphsnew[i] == "\r\n")
   {
   bodyParagraphsnew = bodyParagraphsnew.Where(w => w != bodyParagraphsnew[i]).ToArray();
   }
   ```

Not very nice but maybe it is what you were looking for